# Why VS Code automatically installs extensions when I attach it to a running container?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm developing C# applications on Linux, inside docker.

I use `Dev Containers` to debug my code inside a container. Thus I use the `Attach to Running Container` option to attach to my C# application.

[image]

The problem is that as soon as I attach to the container, it starts installing a couple of extensions automatically. I don't want those extensions to be installed.

It installs `ES Lint` and `C#` extensions. I can understand why it installs `C#`, though I don't want it to automatically install it, because we manually install an older version of that extension.

But why on the Earth does it install `ES Lint` automatically? How can I prevent it from installing any extension at all?

Comment: Check project for the [devcontainer.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/create-dev-container#_create-a-devcontainerjson-file) file and it's contents.

Comment: @GuruStron, that's why I asked here. I have already read the documentation for `devcontainer.json` and I could not find where can I exclude the defaults. Also, we do not use a `devcontainer.json` file now. We decided to use everything default as much as we can. However, I guess we need to bring it back to exlude those nasty defaults.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @GuruStron, there is no need for that. Simply bring up a docker container that contains a C# project, and do not use `devcontainer.json`. Then attach to it. You'll see that it installs two extensions by default.